# Fusing files line by line in a directory according to their type

Tags: bash, shell-script, cat

I have a function, `save`, that is been called by other functions in a `for` loop and the function in question is to fuse files of the same type in a particular directory (copy the contents of each of the files line by lines to a new file according to their types).

The name of the fused file has the format `${x}_type_${y}.log` where `x`and `y` are variables from the other functions where the function save is called and type is the type of the file.

I tried using `cat`, `echo` and `paste` to fuse the file but none of them are functioning. When I run my script, the fused files carry the names as set in the code according to the type of files fused, but either the file fused is empty or it contains the names of the files which are supposed to be fused instead of their contents.

```
for file in *;
do
type=$( echo "$file" | awk -F'[.-]' '{print $2}' )
save () {
 if [[ "$type" == "$type1" ]];
  then
   cat "$file" >> "${x}_First_${y}.log"
 elif [[ "$type" == "$type2" ]];
  then
   cat "$file" >> "${x}_Second_${y}.log"
 elif [[ "$type" == "$type3" ]];
  then
   cat "$file" >> "${x}_Third_${y}.log"
elif [[ "$type" == "$type4" ]];
  then
   cat "$file" >> "${x}_Fourth_${y}.log"
 else
  echo "Nothing to do"
 fi
 }
done
```

I also tried this to try to copy the content of each file to a new file line by line but it didn't still work.

```
for file in *;
do
type=$( echo "$file" | awk -F'[.-]' '{print $2}' )
save () {
  if [[ "$type" == "$type1" ]];
  then
      while IFS= read -r line
do
echo "$line"
echo -e "$line\n" >>"${x}_Request_${y}.log"

done <"$file"
  elif [[ "$type" == "$type2" ]];
  then
      while IFS= read -r line
do
echo "$line"
echo -e "$line\n" >>"${x}_Error_${y}.log"

done <"$file"
 elif [[ "$type" == "$type3" ]];
     then
      while IFS= read -r line
do
echo "$line"
echo -e "$line\n" >>"${x}_Critical_${y}.log"

done <"$file"
 elif [[ "$type" == "$type4" ]];
  then
 while IFS= read -r line
do
echo "$line"
echo -e "$line\n" >>"${x}_Test_${y}.log"

done <"filename"
 else
  echo "Nothing to do"
 fi
}
done
```

This is the entire script

```
#!/bin/bash

env1="dev"
env2="prod"
type1="request"
type2="error"
type3="critical"
type4="test"

save () {
 if [[ "$type" == "$type1" ]];
  then
   cat "$file" >> "${m}_Request_${w}.log"
 elif [[ "$type" == "$type2" ]];
  then
   cat "$file" >> "${m}_Error_${w}.log"
 elif [[ "$type" == "$type3" ]];
  then
   cat "$file" >> "${m}_Critical_${w}.log"
elif [[ "$type" == "$type4" ]];
  then
   cat "$file" >> "${m}_Test_${w}.log"
 else
  echo "Nothing to do"
 fi
 }

week_range () {
 if [[ "$day" -ge 1 && "$day" -le 7 ]];
   then
    w="Wk1"
    save
 elif [[ "$day" -ge 8 && "$day" -le 14 ]];
  then
    w="Wk2"
    save
 elif [[ "$day" -ge 15 && "$day" -le 21 ]];
  then
    w="Wk3"
save
 elif [[ "$day" -ge 22 && "$day" -le 28 ]];
  then
    w="Wk4"
    save
 elif [[ "$day" -ge 29 && "$day" -le 31 ]];
  then
    w="Wk5"
    save
 else
echo "Nothing to do"
fi
 }

month_range () {
 if [[ "$month" -eq 1 ]];
 then
   m="Jan"
   week_range
elif [[ "$month" -eq 2 ]];
then
   m="Feb"
   week_range
elif [[ "$month" -eq 3 ]];
 then
   m="Mar"
   week_range
elif [[ "$month" -eq 4 ]];
 then
   m="Apr"
week_range
elif [[ "$month" -eq 5 ]];
 then
   m="May"
   week_range
elif [[ "$month" -eq 6 ]];
 then
   m="Jun"
   week_range
elif [[ "$month" -eq 7 ]];
then
   m="Jul"
   week_range
elif [[ "$month" -eq 8 ]];
then
   m="Aug"
   week_range
elif [[ "$month" -eq 9 ]];
 then
   m="Sep"
week_range
elif [[ "$month" -eq 10 ]];
 then
  m="Oct"
  week_range
elif [[ "$month" -eq 11 ]];
 then
  m="Nov"
  week_range
elif [[ "$month" -eq 12 ]];
then
  m="Dec"
  week_range
else
   echo "Nothing to do"
fi
 }
for file in *.log;
do
env=$( echo "$file" | awk -F'[.-]' '{print $1}' )
type=$( echo "$file" | awk -F'[.-]' '{print $2}' )
month=$((10#$( echo "$file" | awk -F'[.-]' '{print $4}' )))
day=$((10#$( echo "$file" | awk -F'[.-]' '{print $5}' )))

if [[ "$env" == "$env1" ]];
then
    cd Env1 && { month_range; cd -; }
elif [[ "$env" == "$env2" ]];
  then
    cd Env2 && { month_range; cd -; }
else
  echo "Nothing to do"
fi
done
```

This is how my files look like

```
dev.critical-2021-01-05.log  prod.critical-2021-12-07.log
dev.critical-2021-08-09.log  prod.error-2021-02-21.log
dev.error-2021-08-01.log     prod.error-2021-07-29.log
dev.error-2021-08-07.log     prod.error-2021-10-22.log
dev.request-2021-08-01.log   prod.request-2021-01-02.log
dev.request-2021-08-12.log   prod.request-2021-04-10.log
dev.test-2021-09-03.log
```

This is what I expect to have for both dev and prod in different directories

```
Jan_Critical_Wk1.log         
Jan_Request_Wk1.log          
Jun_Request_Wk1.log  
Mar_Critical_Wk2.log        
May_Error_Wk2.log  
Feb_Error_Wk3.log      
Apr_Request_Wk2.log          
Aug_Critical_Wk1.log         
Aug_Critical_Wk2.log         
Aug_Error_Wk1.log            
Aug_Error_Wk2.log            
Aug_Request_Wk1.log          
Aug_Request_Wk2.log          
Nov_Error_Wk3.log
Oct_Error_Wk4.log
Sep_Request_Wk4.log
Jul_Error_Wk5.log            
Sep_Test_Wk1.log
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add everything we need to reproduce this. Give us a couple of example files, show us how you would run the function on these files and then what we should expect to see as output. This is only a part of your script, since we don't know what the different `$type` variables have or what the `$x` and `$y` variables are. Also, we need to see your file names. Can they have more than one `.`? More than one `-`? Both a `.` and a `-`?

Comment: Hang on, how are you running the function? You only show the function definition here, but you are not actually calling it anywhere.

Comment: You are re-defining the function `save` in each iteration of your loop, but you never call it.

Comment: Ok. Let me show you my whole script so you can see better

Comment: The first `if` in the `save` function reads `cat "file" >>` instead of `cat "$file" >>`.

Comment: Ok. It is a typing error, thanks

Comment: Have you tried running this? Did you look at the errors? Doesn't that help you debug it?

Comment: @terdon yes I tried to run it with the correction of errors but it still not works properly. The files are fused but are empty. And it says no such file or directory for each of the files to be fused

Comment: Yes, precisely. That is the kind of thing you need to mention in your question! It says no file found because you are `cd`ing to the Env directory and then trying to `cat` the file, but the file is not present in the Env directory.

Comment: Do you want the output in the `Env1` and `Env2` directories, or in `prod` and `dev` directories?

Comment: @terdon `prod` and `dev` are not directories, they are just environments of the different files so the output must be in the `Env1` and `Env2` directories

Answer (score 2):

Your error is trying to `cat` the file referenced by `$file` after having moved on to another directory where that file is not available.

You seem to inspect the filenames and categorize them based on that.

The code can be made simpler.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

declare -A envdir

months=( Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec )
envdir=( [dev]=Env1 [prod]=Env2 )

for name in *.log; do
        IFS='.-' read -r env type year month day suffix <<<"$name"

        m=${months[(10#$month) - 1]}
        w="Wk$(( 1 + (10#$day)/7 ))"

        if [ -z "$m" ] || [ ! -d "${envdir[$env]}" ]; then
                echo 'Nothing to do'
                continue
        fi

        cat -- "$name" >>"${envdir[$env]}/${m}_${type^}_$w.log"
done
```

The above use the fact that the directory names for the  types are already part of the filenames.  We just need to up-case the initial characters, which we do with `${type^}`.  The different parts of the filename is read into the variables using `read`.

We pick the month's name from an array based on the month number rather than going through a long `if`, `then`, `else` list.  The week number is computed based on the day. The environment directory to use is stored in an associative array, `envdir`.

We don't need to `cd` into anywhere.

The `nullglob` shell option makes the globbing pattern disappear completely if it doesn't match anything.  Without `nullglob`, the pattern `*.log` would be assigned to `name` and at least one iteration of the loop would take place.

You may also be more restrictive in how you pick the filenames to be sure you only pick up valid files.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob extglob

declare -A envdir

months=( Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec )
envdir=( [dev]=Env1 [prod]=Env2 )

for name in @(dev|prod).@(critical|error)-????-??-??.log; do
        # as before
done
```

Notice the addition of the `extglob` shell option.  It allows us to write a `ksh`-like extended globbing pattern to match the specific names we want to look at.  In particular, it allows us to use `@(pattern|pattern|pattern)` to match one of the enclosed patterns or strings.

Comment: I see, but I'm lost at a point. What does the following code does
`if [ -z "$m" ] || [ ! -d "${envdir[$env]}" ]; then
                echo 'Nothing to do'
                continue
        fi`

Comment: And what is the use of `shopt -s nullglob extglob`

Comment: @NgouabaRosalie I've added explanations of both `nullglob` and `extglob` in the text. For furter info about them, see the `bash` manual. The `if` statement that you ask about is to make sure that we have a value of `$m` that makes sense (is not an empty string) and that the directory that we want to write the file's data into exists.  These are standard tests that all shells can do, and you can read about `-z` and `-d` in the manual for the `test` (or `[`) utility (`man test`, `man [`).

Comment: Ok, it's clear and it works perfectly.